# Access Facebook by RFID chip

Tags: facebook, authentication, rfid

I try to write a Facebook app. This app will communicate with a rfid chip. So what will it do.
When is hold my RFID chip at a kiosk desk it will put on my Facebook for example a "I Like" command.

The main issue will be:
How can i connect my Facebook with my RFID chip. I know you can only access your Facebook by the Facebook page. So can i put my userid or session key on my rfid chip or write into a database so i can use only the RFID serialID. I now there are companies how can do this.

http://www.facebook.com/presence/
http://www.allfacebook.com/coca-cola-marketing-2010-08

I hope there is someone how can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the solution after my project over, but still keeping my last answers. The key for solving this project is to have an access token. Basically, when you have the access token with granted permission (access profile, checkin, post photo ...), you can do anything.

When using RFID, QRBarcode ... the content that scanning from reader is a string that linked to access token. Your Facebook App must query the input string and find appropriate acess_token, then use it for check in, post photo via Facebook Graph APIs.

I am asking my client to allow me posting the example application on my technical blog. Hope they will approve for next couple weeks.

[--- origin answser----]
I am also investigating this thing - using RIDF chip to checkin or like a Facebook page. Not really starting yet, but my thought for the flow should be:

- You must have an RIDF reader connects to a PC
- Giving your users the RIDF chip, and users must authorizes their RIDF chip via Facebook Presence
- Developing your Facebook app that receives a token from reader. Base on the access token, your app allows user like or checkin

Comment: did you post the example code on your blog? I am trying to do the same